# Ingress - How to dispath with base URLs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have two services with the names `svc1` and `svc2`. Can I make ingress dispatch the same domain with different base URLs to each service, i.e.:

`ingress.domain/svc1/path-here` -> svc1 gets this request, with path rewritten as `/path-here`

`ingress.domain/svc2/path-here` -> svc2 gets this request, with path rewritten as `/path-here`

So I can use one domain for all services on this k8s instance?

Comment: you meant: after you got domain access `ingress.domain/svc2/path-here` it will redirect to `ingress.domain/path-here`

Comment: I mean the pod of `svc2` service will get the request and see it's request URL is `ingress.domain/path-here`. `ingress.domain` resolves to the k8s instance IP.

Comment: please share your exmple ingress ymal file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: public-dev
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: public-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: developer.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: test-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test-service(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: test-service-2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /test-service-2(/|$)(.*)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - developer.example.com
    secretName: public-dev
```